# Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException after Xamarin toolset upgrade

Tags: android, xamarin

After upgrading my build server from Xamarin.Android from 4.x to 5.1 and I try to open an activity in my Xamarin.Android app from another app, I get the following errors

```
Exception of type 'Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException' was thrown.|Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException: Exception of type 'Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException' was thrown.

android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {net.uk.mobilecomputing.p1sync/p2d2syncmono.Priority1Upgrade}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Answer (score 1):

[Xamarin docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/working_with_androidmanifest.xml/#Activity_Name) says "Beginning with Xamarin.Android 5.1, the type name of an activity is based on the MD5SUM of the assembly-qualified name of the type being exported."

You can override this new behaviour by explicitly specifying the fully qualified activity name, e.g.

```
[Activity (Name="awesome.demo.activity")]
public class MyActivity : Activity
{
}
```

**Symptoms**

You can observe the md5 mangling if you look at the Xamarin.Android 4.x generated AndroidManifest.xml (from the APK or `\obj\Release\android\AndroidManifest.xml` in your build folder)

```
<activity android:label="Diagnostics" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="myapp.DiagnosticsActivity" />
```

Xamarin.Android 5.1 generated AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:label="Diagnostics" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="md5639bd49aa1d9951fabb0323996a58a3f.DiagnosticsActivity" />
```